# If the observable universe keeps expanding would we eventualy see light 24/7.... clouds permiting?

Tags: astronomy, astrophysics, measurements, observational-astronomy, astrophotography

If we can see more observable universe could there be a time when day and night looked the same?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11014/2451

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, due to the [Redshift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redshift) the light of stars further away will be shifted more and more towards the infrared (and beyond), becoming invisible to the eye.